# I need to be able to obtain only the string that makes up the Id in a query to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB, mongoose and typescript and I need to keep the document ids when I query but I can only get the type _id: new ObjectId("62aa4bddae588fb13e8df552") . I only need to keep the string "62aa4bddae588fb13e8df552" to later store it and do other processing. I can't get rid of the new ObjectId

```
async findById(id:string) {
    const convert = {"_id":id}
    const userfindById = await userModel.findById(convert);
    const iD = userfindById?._id
    return userfindById;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ObjectId** is just a type :

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid

If you want to get the string you can extract with `_id.toString()`, if you want to store the string you should change the type of `_id` (or create a new property)

Comment: perfect, at the same time that I store it I already get only the chain. thanks